# Google Maps fails to load. Hangs on authenticationService.authenticate

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google Maps application that works perfectly on multiple developer machines but fails to run when deployed to an Internet facing Web server.

The developer machines all access the application using

```
http://localhost
```

However on the Internet facing web server the application is of course accessed via a valid domain

```
http://<Some Domain>/<application>
```

Debugging on the browser side I see that the last call made from the browser is

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/AuthenticationService.Authenticate?1shttp://<the proper domain>/corpsuser/User_Page.html&callback=_xdc_._9p58yx&token=125651
```

(Domain name masked)

The Maps application code where things hang seems to be the javascript:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
```

The element 'map' and object mapOptions are properly defined (after all, app works fine on dev machines)

I am guessing this is a licensing/Key issue.

I logged in to the Google Account used for enabling the Google Maps API and generated browser key and also added/associated the domain to the key but that didn't work. Noticed that there is a message that said it could take up to 5 minutes for changes to reflect. So waited for some time and still no luck.

Digging deeper, I saw that some of the calls, for example the snapToRoads API take in the Server API Key as a parameter.

However the call where the application hangs is the first call to setup the map and does not take in the API key.

The google documentation says I need to use this tag somewhere

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Where should I add it? and Do I have to define the initMap function? or should it be used as-is?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about posting your code? That might help.

Comment: mine its a website rei360.al/

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [sample code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple) in where you need to place the line `<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" type="text/javascript"></script>`

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You will notice that all example in these [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/) uses that line, because you need this to load the Google Maps JavaScript API.

For the **callback parameter**, it explains [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API) that when the async attributes lets the browser render the website while the Maps JavaScript API loads, when the API is ready, it will call the function specified using the **callback** parameter.

Comment: Updated works perfectly on localhost (Dev machine) but does not work when deployed to the live production server. It again blocks on the authentication call. `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/AuthenticationService.Authenticate?1shttp:<Application URL>&<API KEY>&callback=_xdc_._yf0fuy&token=8983` The API key is passed out properly in each call, where as it was missing earlier. I also confirmed that there are no Google API JavaScript error messages in the browser JavaScript console. However when I checked the Google Account dashboard, I do not see any Call history for the key.

Comment: @Sudhashbahu did you got it fixed? I am facing the same issue, please help.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and it turned out be related to caching. Some of the code involved in the loading and display of maps was in an external .js file that was being cached by Cloudflare. When I deployed to production, it was still using the old js. I needed to manually purge the cache within Cloudflare.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same setup (devolper host vs. public host), facing the same symptoms (map shows on developer host while map loading stalled on public host with last log line on browser console "...maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/AuthenticationService.Authenticate?1shttp...&token=64530 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 25ms]" the reason for failure was that (only on public host) the map container-div contained legacy direct element style formatting disabling display that overrode the used formatting so that the map stayed unvisible.

The probability the reported problem will have exactly the same reason might be small, but there are 2 findings:

1. The loading of Google maps api code and data might stop at unexpected positions as the reason for my failure was in no way related to authentication.
2. If a developer version is running, starting to derive the public version with an exact copy of the developer version seems to be a good, at least handy practice.

By the way, there are ways to not use the cited code to use Google maps, but it can also be done by dynamically include it (independent of async and defer settings).

Comment: Your site is load under https ? Because some api has problema with not secure connection

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience with Chrome browser on Android. The reason was Chrome's data saver option which was enabled. The problem got solved on disabling this option. The second option is to go with SSL. Chrome does not compress the pages for data saving served as https.